# Is the word "click" appropriate for touchscreen applications?

Tags: android, ios, click, terminology

When developing android/ios (or other touchscreen) applications, is the term "click" the best appropriate term when describing **to a user** a desired action. (This question has nothing to do with coding terms, like OnClickListener.)

E.g.,

> *Click* the OK button to proceed.

I'm not sure that the words "touch" or "press" have the same connotation.

**I'm not looking for opinion. I'm hoping for a reference or established guideline of the current industry standard.**

Comment: tap is generally used in iOS

Comment: Choose Ok to Proceed

Comment: Isn't "Choose" escaping the questions? "Click Ok" was just an example. What about "Long-click the list item" or "Click top-right corner of the screen"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the action of the gesture. For android the following will do

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html

press, lift        -'Touch' most appropriate.

press, wait, lift  -'Press' most appropriate.

I would use this if i was you. Then again i've not seen any true reference or established guideline.

Answer (score 1):

This does not really answer your question but instead of deciding which word to use, another way is to change your dialog message.

Example for

```
 Click the OK button to proceed
```

You can change to

```
Do you want to proceed
```

And the button text change to "Yes" and "No"

As for "Long-click the list item" or "Click top-right corner of the screen" the best is to use either touch/press.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this might give you a clear idea between **click** and **touch**.

Now the **android** is so boomed OS that it is used in every type of devices such as smartphones or tv boxes. And when we say **Android Smart TV Box**, we can't say the user to touch the TV where they can't do that. That's why then we can suggest them to **click OK button to proceed**, because they are using some wireless mouse.

In your case, If you wish your application totally should run in smartphones and not other android devices then we can say **TAP or Touch** to continue. or if you want to use your app in smart boxes also then Click would be the right word.